# Wireless multi function scanner / printer

Tags: hardware-compatibility, wifi

Can someone recommend me a wireless multi function scanner / printer that will work with Ubuntu? If something like this exists at all..

Answer (score 2):

I have had good success using HP and Epson printers.  Here is a list of supported [Ubuntu printers/Multi-function printers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Printers), You could also check out [Open Printing](http://www.openprinting.org/printers) to find a supported Linux printer. Good luck

Comment: HP++ HP seems to have the best *nix support there is.

Comment: Thanks! I've also had success with HP, but is this true for wireless printers as well?

Comment: Looks like yes.  This post gives a HP wireless printer how to, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1576806&highlight=hp+wireless+printers . I do not have any experience with it.